# AttributeError: module 'file2' has no attribute 'A'

Tags: python-3.x

I have two python files file1.py and file2.py while accessing file2 variables in file1 I'm getting the error

file1.py contains:

```
from file2 import A

B = 10
print(A+B)
```

file2.py contains:

```
def func():
  ------ # ignore this function
  ------ # ignore this function

if '__name__'=='__main__':
   A = 20
```

Then getting error :

> AttributeError: module 'file2' has no attribute 'A'

How to access variables in other python file which are under

```
if '__name__'=='__main__':
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can import variables under

```
if '__name__'=='__main__':
```

If the python interpreter is running that module (the source file) as the main program, it sets the special **name** variable to have a value “**main**”. If this file is being imported from another module, **name** will be set to the module’s name.
`if __name__ == “main”:` is used to execute some code only if the file was run directly, and not imported.

Instead, check this out:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    A=20
else: 
    A=30
```

Now when you import file2 and print A, A will be 30.

Comment: Is it impossible to access variables if they are under  if '__name__'=='__main__': ?

Comment: if __name__=="main": is used to execute some code only if the file was run directly and not imported, so I guess it is not possible to access those variables.

Comment: @krishna the variables you want to access on importing the module to another, use 'name'==name of the module.